# Why isn't the throw-catch statement automatic?

Tags: try-catch, throw

So I know that the `try`/`throw`/`catch` statement is for exceptions, but why doesn't the programming languge automate that, since almost every exception can be fixed by it?

Comment: What language are you referring to and what exactly do you mean by *"automate"* and *"fixed"*? As it stands I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Something called English.

Comment: Do I really have to say it? Which programming language? C++? Java? C#? If every exception woulf be caught right where it is thrown, what would be their use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very easy to to catch every  every exception (taking Java as an example), you could catch *every* exception which are all subclasses of `Exception` which is itself a subclass of `Throwable`.

But then you would never know when something has gone wrong. Exceptions are necessary and useful, and sometimes, when something goes wrong its important that its known about!

A useful way of thinking about them are as "hot potato's" - you can pass them on, but at some point, somewhere, they have to be dealt with